# Agrupar resultado do Mysql no PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho duas tabelas no meu banco de dados a `cad_usuario` e a `cad_automovel`. O Usuário cadastrado na primeira tabela pode ter varios veiculos cadastrado na segunda tabela.

```
SELECT aut.usuario_id, aut.marca, aut.modelo, aut.ano, usr.id, usr.nome_completo, usr.rg FROM cad_automovel as aut INNER JOIN cad_usuario as usr on usr.id = aut.usuario_id
```

O problema é que na hora de mostrar o resultado no PHP, ele mostra duas linhas para o mesmo usuario

```
 ----------
id_usuario: 1
nome_completo: John Doe
rg: 000.000.000
aut.usuario_id: 1
aut.marca: marca1
aut.modelo: modelo1
aut.ano: 2017
---------
id_usuario: 1
nome_completo: John Doe
rg: 000.000.000
aut.usuario_id: 1
aut.marca: marca22
aut.modelo: modelo22
aut.ano: 2007
```

Preciso que ficasse mais ou menos assim:

```
    ---------------
    id_usuario: 1
    nome_completo: John Doe
    rg: 000.000.000
    aut.usuario_id: 1
    aut.marca: marca1, marca22
    aut.modelo: modelo1, marca22
    aut.ano: 2017, 2007
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para agrupar várias linhas separando por vírgula, você pode usar o `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT
   usr.id,
   GROUP_CONCAT( aut.marca ),
   GROUP_CONCAT( aut.modelo ),
   GROUP_CONCAT( aut.ano ),
   usr.nome_completo,
   usr.rg
FROM
   cad_automovel AS aut
   LEFT JOIN cad_usuario as usr
      ON usr.id = aut.usuario_id
GROUP BY
   usr.id
```

Veja funcionando no **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/deb46/1)**.

#### Notas

- O `GROUP_CONCAT` tem um limite definido por `group_concat_max_len`. *Strings* de maior comprimento são truncadas. Este valor costuma ser 8192 (bytes). Se precisar de mais, precisa ajustar a configuração;
- O MySQL não aceita espaço entre o nome da função e a lista de argumentos. O correto é `GROUP_CONCAT( campo )`, e não `GROUP_CONCAT ( campo )`;
- Dentro da chamada da função podem ser utilizados os operadores `DISTINCT` e `ASC` ou `DESC` para organizar os resultados. Veja mais detalhes no manual.

> Manual: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: `group_concat does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual`

Comment: @LucasOlivier acrescentei um SQL Fiddle demonstrando o funcionamento correto da _query_. A função `GROUP_CONCAT` está presente em todas as versões atualmente mantidas para o MySQL (5.5 e acima). Você pode estar com algum erro de sintaxe logo anterior à função (ou estar usando outro banco que não corresponde ao que foi perguntado).

Comment: realmente estava com erro de sintaxe. Consegui agrupar os valores no `SQL`. Agora vou tentar mostrar no `PHP`, excelente resposta! Obrigado.

Comment: LucasOlivier ia comentar agora, pode ter sido dado um espaço antes do (, como o colega @Jeferson mencionou no chat da rede. tem que ser `GROUP_CONCAT(` colado